# Google Cloud Storage thru App Engine pricing

Tags: java, python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage, blobstore

I'm planning to use Google Cloud Storage to store user uploaded images and videos to my GAE app (since GCS seems cheaper than blobstore in GB stored per month). I understand that I can use the images thru the blobstore API for image manipulation according to [this document](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/googlecloudstorageclient/#Java_Blobstore_API).

But taking a look at the [pricing](https://developers.google.com/storage/pricing#pricing) I notice there's a network transfer cost of 0.12 per GB. Does that cost add to the standard GAE outgoing bandwidth ([that](https://developers.google.com/appengine/pricing)'s also 0.12 per GB) making it 0.24/GB for using GCS thru GAE or network does not apply thru GAE? Any programming workaround to avoid the double charge?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're using the GAE APIs to access files stored in GCS then there is no bandwidth charge.